# About using AWS elasticache as a temporary git repository storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, serverless

I am developing a service that analyzes the git repository. It is being developed serverless.
For repository analysis, I need to clone and save space temporarily. Is it possible to use aws elasticache as repository storage space?

Comment: ElastiCache is an in-memory key-value store (think of it as a distributed hashtable). Do you have a plan for how you would use such a store for your application? And would the cost of running a separate server exceed the cost of a local hashtable in a large-memory Lambda container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd have to write code to copy all the files in the git repository into key value pairs to put in elastic cache

elastic cache is great for a use case where several different services all want to read and write data at the same time at high speed

For your use case, S3 might be a better choice